# Inverse function of $y=2x+\sin x$

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse

I was doing a long exercise when come to this point: calculate the inverse function of $y=2x+\sin x (x \in\mathbb R) $ and its derivative.
I know that the derivative of an inverse function is $1/f'(x)$ but it is not enough as $x=f^{-1}(y)$. So I tried to find the inverse function but I'm completely stuck just in this point.
Can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Do you mean $\sin x$

Comment: yes, in Italy we used to write senx

Comment: Hi @Dipok! $$\color{blue}{\Large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Comment: @Shaun thank you very much :-)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find a closed form of the inverse of your function.

Comment: I just managed to solve the exercise without finding the inverse function using only the derivative of the inverse function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write $x=2y+\sin(y)$, then $1=2y'+\cos(y)\cdot y'$, hence $y'=1/(2+\cos(y))$, that will be the derivative of the inverse.  If you can solve that differential equation you'll have the inverse ...